# real work examples of bind in javascript

Tags: javascript

What are some real world examples of **bind** in javascript which would help in understanding? Also explaining the use case in the projects would also be very helpful.

Comment: Look at the reactjs framework. They use bind Alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common situation is when you want to pass an object's method as a callback (there are a lot of callbacks in JS).

Consider this super-simple object:

```
var logger = {
    name: "myLogger",
    log: function(txt) {
        console.log(this.name+":", txt);
    }
};

logger.log("Hello there") // myLogger: Hello there
```

You may want to pass `log` as a callback to `forEach` to log a whole array of elements:

```
var messages = ["first message", "second message", "third message"];
messages.forEach(function(msg) {
    logger.log(msg);
});
```

The simpler way to say that is:

```
messages.forEach(logger.log.bind(logger));
```

You cannot just say `forEach(logger.log)` because `this` would not be passed properly.

Answer (score 1):

### Example 1:

this is a simple example that can help you understand the bind function :

let's say you have 2 objects and a method for both of them :

```
var getName = function () {
    return this.name;
}

var obj1 = {
   name : "obj1",
   getName : getName
}

var obj2 = {
   name : "obj2",
   getName : getName
}
```

now if you want for example to get the name of obj2 from obj1, at first thought you would say :

```
obj1.getObj2Name = obj2.getName
```

but here, when you call `obj1.getObj2Name()` you will get as result `obj1` simply because the value of `this` keyword is in this case equals to `obj1`. And if you do this :

```
obj1.getObj2Name = obj2.getName();
```

this would be an attribute and sure, it won't be updated after changes of the name of `obj2`. so the solution is to use the bind method that allows you to build a function with the value of the context (`this`) given as argument.

```
obj1.getObj2Name = obj1.getName.bind(obj2);
obj1.getObj2Name = obj2.getName.bind(obj2);
obj1.getObj2Name = getName.bind(obj2);
// All of them are the same
```

### Example 2:

The example posted by kos, reminds me of something I always do:
when you use Ajax of jquery and you need to show the result, I used to call the console.log inside a callback like this :

```
$.ajax({
   url : "http://url",
   success : function (data) {
       console.log(data);
   }
});
```

when I try this :

```
$.ajax({url: "http://url", success: console.log });
```

I always get an error, because inside the success call back, `console.log` loses its `context` which should be the `console` object

so one of the solutions I do, is using `bind` :

```
$.ajax({url: "http://url", success: console.log.bind(console) });
```

This is how I always get the log function with the `console` object as context

### call and apply:

Another two interesting functions that look the same as `bind`, are `call` and `apply`. The difference is that `call` and `apply` allow you to get the value returned by the function with the given context and not a function that you can call everytime you want.